# Change alpha of the first image in tabbar SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm using a ESTabBarController to build a TabBar. I need to access the first imageView to change its `alpha`, everytime it is the `selectedItem`. The tabbarcontroller is under a UINavigationController by the way. Can I please get some help on that? I can provide the code if needed. Im trying to change the alpha when on `didSet` of the `selectedIndex`

I've tried

`navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.compactMap{$0 as? UIImageView}.first.alpha = 1` this returns a nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ESTabBarController` is actually the perfect framework for what you want to do and so much more, I just had a look at it because of your question! So, the following code should pretty surely do what you intended. Chuck it into a new single view application's `ViewController.swift` and try for yourself.

You can customise the second button in its selected state however you wish by changing the `ExampleBasicContentView`. If you want to make all TabBarItems behave the same, add the `ExampleBasicContentView()` as the first parameter of the initializers just like I did for the second item.

```
import UIKit
import ESTabBarController

class ViewController: ESTabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v1 = ExampleViewController()
        let v2 = ExampleViewController()
        let v3 = ExampleViewController()
        let v4 = ExampleViewController()
        let v5 = ExampleViewController()

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleBasicContentView(), title: "Find", image: UIImage(named: "find"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "find_1"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(title: "Photo", image: UIImage(named: "photo"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "photo_1"))
        v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(title: "Favor", image: UIImage(named: "favor"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "favor_1"))
        v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(title: "Me", image: UIImage(named: "me"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "me_1"))

        tabBar.shadowImage = nil
        viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]
    }
}


class ExampleBasicContentView: ESTabBarItemContentView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        highlightIconColor = iconColor.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        highlightTextColor = textColor.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted this because its precise and clear though I did not use this because I already had these classes and it was just missing a line of code. I solved it though.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I'm glad you figured it out! What was missing?

Comment: essentially what you had `highlightIconColor = iconColor.withAlphaComponent(0.4)` but my own variation.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used:

```swift
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[i].image.alpha = // Your value
```

Comment: image does not have a member `alpha`. Besides, I need the imageView not the image.